# Ansible error while trying to change "command: sudo ..." to a module with become

Tags: ansible

I have got a simple playbook that just restarts a service:

```
- hosts: rmq-node2.lan
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Restart RabbitMQ   
      become: yes
      become_method: sudo
      systemd:
        name: rabbitmq-server
        state: restarted
        force: yes
```

Inventory:

```
rabbit:
  hosts:
    rmq-node1.lan: {}

all:
  vars:

    ansible_user: usbp-deploy-adt
    ansible_password: q12345
    ansible_become_pass: "{{ ansible_password }}"
```

It gives me the following error:

```
fatal: [rmq-node2.lan]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": 
{"discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"}, 
"changed": false, 
"module_stderr": "Shared connection to rmq-node2.lan closed.\r\n", 
"module_stdout": "\r\n", 
"msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", 
"rc": 1}
```

-vvv mode:

```
<rmq-node2.lan> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: usbp-deploy-adt
<rmq-node2.lan> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d9 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'User="usbp-deploy-adt"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/3f3f334328 rmq-node2.lan '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~usbp-deploy-adt && sleep 0'"'"''
<rmq-node2.lan> (0, b'/home/usbp-deploy-adt\n', b'')
<rmq-node2.lan> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: usbp-deploy-adt
<rmq-node2.lan> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d9 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'User="usbp-deploy-adt"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/3f3f334328 rmq-node2.lan '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /home/usbp-deploy-adt/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1617921012.2138484-192947282332368 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1617921012.2138484-192947282332368="` echo /home/usbp-deploy-adt/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1617921012.2138484-192947282332368 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
<rmq-node2.lan> (0, b'ansible-tmp-1617921012.2138484-192947282332368=/home/usbp-deploy-adt/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1617921012.2138484-192947282332368\n', b'')
<rmq-node2.lan> Attempting python interpreter discovery
<rmq-node2.lan> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: usbp-deploy-adt
<rmq-node2.lan> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d9 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'User="usbp-deploy-adt"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/3f3f334328 rmq-node2.lan '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo PLATFORM; uname; echo FOUND; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'/usr/bin/python'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.7'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.6'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.5'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python2.7'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python2.6'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'/usr/libexec/platform-python'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'/usr/bin/python3'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; echo ENDFOUND && sleep 0'"'"''
<rmq-node2.lan> (0, b'PLATFORM\nLinux\nFOUND\n/usr/bin/python\n/usr/bin/python3.6\n/usr/bin/python2.7\n/usr/libexec/platform-python\n/usr/bin/python3\n/usr/bin/python\nENDFOUND\n', b'')
<rmq-node2.lan> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: usbp-deploy-adt
<rmq-node2.lan> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d9 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'User="usbp-deploy-adt"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/3f3f334328 rmq-node2.lan '/bin/sh -c '"'"'/usr/bin/python && sleep 0'"'"''
<rmq-node2.lan> (0, b'{"osrelease_content": "NAME=\\"Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server\\"\\nVERSION=\\"7.9 (Maipo)\\"\\nID=\\"rhel\\"\\nID_LIKE=\\"fedora\\"\\nVARIANT=\\"Server\\"\\nVARIANT_ID=\\"server\\"\\nVERSION_ID=\\"7.9\\"\\nPRETTY_NAME=\\"Red Hat Enterprise Linux\\"\\nANSI_COLOR=\\"0;31\\"\\nCPE_NAME=\\"cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.9:GA:server\\"\\nHOME_URL=\\"https://www.redhat.com/\\"\\nBUG_REPORT_URL=\\"https://bugzilla.redhat.com/\\"\\n\\nREDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT=\\"Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7\\"\\nREDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.9\\nREDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT=\\"Red Hat Enterprise Linux\\"\\nREDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION=\\"7.9\\"\\n", "platform_dist_result": ["redhat", "7.9", "Maipo"]}\n', b'')
Using module file /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/system/systemd.py
<rmq-node2.lan> PUT /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-2929y0v8kody/tmpl7fkd6zd TO /home/usbp-deploy-adt/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1617921012.2138484-192947282332368/AnsiballZ_systemd.py
<rmq-node2.lan> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d9 sftp -o BatchMode=no -b - -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'User="usbp-deploy-adt"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/3f3f334328 '[rmq-node2.lan]'
<rmq-node2.lan> (0, b'sftp> put /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-2929y0v8kody/tmpl7fkd6zd /home/usbp-deploy-adt/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1617921012.2138484-192947282332368/AnsiballZ_systemd.py\n', b'')
<rmq-node2.lan> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: usbp-deploy-adt
<rmq-node2.lan> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d9 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'User="usbp-deploy-adt"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/3f3f334328 rmq-node2.lan '/bin/sh -c '"'"'chmod u+x /home/usbp-deploy-adt/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1617921012.2138484-192947282332368/ /home/usbp-deploy-adt/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1617921012.2138484-192947282332368/AnsiballZ_systemd.py && sleep 0'"'"''
<rmq-node2.lan> (0, b'', b'')
<rmq-node2.lan> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: usbp-deploy-adt
<rmq-node2.lan> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d9 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'User="usbp-deploy-adt"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/3f3f334328 -tt rmq-node2.lan '/bin/sh -c '"'"'sudo -H -S  -p "[sudo via ansible, key=qejohkgmxxluzqnxhpvqakuitlgmqaoe] password:" -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-qejohkgmxxluzqnxhpvqakuitlgmqaoe ; /usr/bin/python /home/usbp-deploy-adt/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1617921012.2138484-192947282332368/AnsiballZ_systemd.py'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''
Escalation succeeded
<rmq-node2.lan> (1, b'\r\n', b'Shared connection to rmq-node2.lan closed.\r\n')
<rmq-node2.lan> Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Shared connection to rmq-node2.lan closed.
<rmq-node2.lan> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: usbp-deploy-adt
<rmq-node2.lan> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d9 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'User="usbp-deploy-adt"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/3f3f334328 rmq-node2.lan '/bin/sh -c '"'"'rm -f -r /home/usbp-deploy-adt/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1617921012.2138484-192947282332368/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'"'"''
<rmq-node2.lan> (0, b'', b'')
fatal: [rmq-node2.lan]: FAILED! => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "Shared connection to rmq-node2.lan closed.\r\n",
    "module_stdout": "\r\n",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
    "rc": 1
}
```

However, if I change the playbook to the following:

```
- hosts: rmq-node2.lan
  tasks:
    - name: Restart RabbitMQ   
      command: "sudo systemctl restart rabbitmq-server"
```

everything works just fine.
How can I avoid using command/shell/etc. with `sudo` and replace it with built in modules and `become`?

Error appears both on python2 and python3 with ansible versions 2.9.1 and 2.9.10

Edit 1: sudoers on a remote machine (comments are omitted):

```
Defaults   !visiblepw

Defaults    always_set_home
Defaults    match_group_by_gid

Defaults    always_query_group_plugin

Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    env_keep =  "COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE KDEDIR LS_COLORS"
Defaults    env_keep += "MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY"

Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL

## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)       ALL


## Read drop-in files from /etc/sudoers.d (the # here does not mean a comment)
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d


usbp-deploy-adt ALL=(ALL)NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/journalctl *
usbp-deploy-adt ALL=(rabbitmq) ALL
usbp-deploy-adt ALL=(ALL)NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/systemctl * rabbitmq-server

#usbp-deploy-adt ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Edit 2: switching `become_method` to `su`:

```
fatal: [rmq-node2.lan]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Incorrect su password"
}
```

Comment: Do you have full sudo rights for the connecting user? Can you edit your question and add the studio configuration for that use on the target host?

Comment: @Zeitounator added sudoers file. How can i not have enough privilege if a simple `command` action works well?

Comment: Because `sudo` can allow one/a few commands (that will work when you test manually) whereas [ansible requires privilege escalation to be general](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#privilege-escalation-must-be-general). And it is not the case: your `usbp-deploy-adt` has limited command access. This can't work for ansible. (and congrats for the translation of my previous comment typed on my phone....)

Comment: @Zeitounator okay, i got it. In this case it is impossible to use ansible modules. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would check if there is any issues with the privilege escalation method run by ansible.

Is your user part of the wheel group, or set up on the sudoers file (depending on the linux distribution)?

default privilege escalation method is sudo, which you can change by using `--become-method=METHOD` when running the ansible command (substitute METHOD with su for example, to see if the behavior changes.

You might have to add a password for this test, with the parameter `ask-become-pass`

If changing the privilege escalation method works, i would post some more information about distribution and sudoers/wheel configuration.

to make sure the user is configured properly.

Here is some documentation about `become` in ansible:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html

Comment: Added sudoers. Password is defined in inventory, su doesn't work either. If i add `usbp-deploy-adt ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL` in sudoers everything works, but i can't use it due to security reasons

Comment: @GeorgeAnikeev: then you can't use ansible with privilege escalation. Your only options are: connect directly as root, or don't use ansible.

Comment: You dont need to use ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL. Just allow the user you use on ansible to be able to escalate privileges. Depending on the OS this is as simple as making the user a member of the wheel group.

there should be a line in your sudoers files that reads something like:
%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL